# Android - Using same keyboard, as the browser adress bar, in a EditText

Tags: android, browser, keyboard, android-edittext

I wanted the keyboard that android have with the shortcuts to ".com" to an editText, and another for an email input with the "@".

I've tried different things like this:

```
email_edit.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
facebook_edit.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_EDIT_TEXT);
twitter_edit.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_URI);
```

but nothing works and the keyboard that appears is the normal one.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your EditText you can set the input type:

```
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
```

In code you can use:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
```

Comment: Still no difference... the keyboard that appears is the one that the others EditTexts call by default.

Comment: Correction, it worked using XML. But why does it work using XML and not by code?